# integrating kafka in an existing spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have found a lot of tutorials on spring-kafka with spring-boot and have successfully implemented them. Why do all the tutorials use spring-boot? Is there some kind of dependency in spring-kafka or is it the best solution?

I already have a spring project and I'm trying to add a spring-kafka maven module in it. My main project's pom.xml looks like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com</groupId>

<artifactId>Catalog</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>Catalog</name>

<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<modules>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>db</module>
    <module>web</module>
    <module>Test2</module>
    <module>entity</module>
    <module>history</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

My module's pom.xml looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" 
xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>Catalog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com</groupId>

<artifactId>history</artifactId>

<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>history</name>

<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- 
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

With these dependencies the project does not run. I have to replace

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>Catalog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

with the below code from the tutorial to make it work.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

How do I make spring-kafka run without using spring-boot?

App.java

```
package org.history;

public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        KafkaTest test = new KafkaTest();
        test.start();
    }
}
```

KafkaTest.java

```
package org.history;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import 
org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.config.ContainerProperties;

public class KafkaTest {

public void start() {
    System.out.println("starting");
    ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("cscart_product_topic");

    containerProps.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<Integer, String>() {

        @Override
        public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> message) {
            System.out.println("received: " + message);
        }
    });

    KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> container = createContainer(containerProps);
    container.setBeanName("testAuto");
    container.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    // wait a bit for the container to start

    KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template = createTemplate();
    template.setDefaultTopic("cscart_product_topic");
    template.sendDefault(0, "foo");
    template.sendDefault(2, "bar");
    template.sendDefault(0, "baz");
    template.sendDefault(2, "qux");
    template.flush();
    container.stop();
}

private KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> createContainer(
        ContainerProperties containerProps) {
    Map<String, Object> props = consumerProps();
    DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf =
                    new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String>(props);
    KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> container =
                    new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProps);
    return container;
}

private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> createTemplate() {
    Map<String, Object> senderProps = senderProps();
    ProducerFactory<Integer, String> pf =
      new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<Integer, String>(senderProps);
    KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(pf);
    return template;
}

private Map<String, Object> consumerProps() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "cscart_product");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return props;
}

private Map<String, Object> senderProps() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    return props;
}

}
```

Adding this as mentioned in the offical doc.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I get an error in KafkaTest.java on the first line

```
package org.history;
```

The error says "The type org.springframework.messaging.Message cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"

Comment: U can always use vanilla apache kafka dependecy and implement from there. It will give you flexibility and control over entire process. Not saying that spring kafka lacks in that department

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this in your pom.xml is enough to use spring-kafka without spring boot.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Have a look in the [official site](https://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/)

Comment: I get this error on the package name after adding this "The type org.springframework.messaging.Message cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

Comment: You should get the `spring-messaging` jar as a transitive dependency.